# Custom Header in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Problem with custom header in incoming request.
The header must be called Authorization Bearer
Anyone have idea how to called Header?

Haproxy.cfg:

```
 http-request set-var(req.token)  str(""),lua.create_access_token
 http-request add-header "Authorization Bearer" %[var(req.token)]
```

version 2.4

Comment: The header name is `Authorization`, `Bearer` is the auth scheme and part of the header value, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: The header must be named Authorization Bearer . Is this possible?

Comment: There are no blankspaces in header names. `Bearer` is part of the value.